# Logic: How to find a c-variant of a quantified formula in an interpretation?

Tags: logic

Taken from Daniel Bonevac's *Deduction Introductory Symbolic Logic*, page 194:

Let D = $\{ a \}$, $[a] = a$, $[F] = \{ a \}$, and $[R] = \{ <a, a> \}$. What is the truth value of these formulas on this interpretation ?

> For some $x$, $(Fx \rightarrow Rxx)$

I understand how to find out whether the formula is true on this certain interpretations (like the one above), but how can I find the variant(s) of the interpretation? We went over this a bit in class but I was pretty lost. I thought Bonevac would cover it in the chapter, but the word 'variant' is not even listed in the book's index.

My first assumption is to plug in the letters in the domain to find the variant and it's truth value. For example, if the domain above was changed to {a, b}, the b-variant would be $Fb \rightarrow Rbb$, and it's truth value would be true because $F \rightarrow F$. Is that right, or am I totally off the ball here?

(The above formula/interpretation is not a part of my hw, it is just an easy example problem I took from the book to try to understand variants / how to find them!)

Comment: I do not know was your book means as "variant"; but, if you change the domain, you must redefine also the *interpretation* of the *predicates* $F$ and $R$.

Comment: Perhaps it refers to *c-variants*, see page 192 ?

Answer (score 1):

The *Problem* at page 194 is relative to *Interpretations* of quantified formulas.

You must review the basic definition : page 189 and the clause for assigning truth values to quantified formulas : page 191-192.

You can see that

> to judge the truth value of a quantified formula on an interpretation $\mathcal{M}$, we can look at the truth values of an instance of that formula on *c-variants* of $\mathcal{M}$ that are just like $\mathcal{M}$, except that they may assign different objects from the domain to the constant $c$ substituted for the quantified variable.

The clauses at page 192 formalized the semantic interpretation for quantifier :

> $[\exists v \mathcal{A}]_\mathcal{M} = T$ iff $\mathcal{A}[c/v]_\mathcal{M} = T$ for some *c-variant* $\mathcal{M'}$ of $\mathcal{M}$
>
> $[\forall v \mathcal{A}]_\mathcal{M} = T$ iff $\mathcal{A}[c/v]_\mathcal{M} = T$ for every *c-variant* $\mathcal{M'}$ of $\mathcal{M}$.

In order to understand the *Problem*, you must :

*i)* understand" the "intuitive meaning" of *quantifiers*

*ii)* review the definition of *instance* of a formula

*iii)* practice with the "mechanism" of *c-variants*.

Specifically for the *Problem* at page 194, having defined a *domain* $D = \{ a \}$ with only one element, you cannot have *c-variants*. This means that, if $F(a)$ is *true* in the domain *D*, also $\forall x F(x)$ will be.

Intuitively, if the domain of the interpretation has only one object $a$, if $F$ holds for that object, it holds *for every* object in the domain.

Now, try to do all the cases of the *Problem* with domain $D = \{ a \}$ and then go on with the other *Problems*, until you reach that with domain $D = \{ a , b \}$, where you need to use *c-variants*.

Comment: I think I'm confused because Bonevac only discusses this briefly, in one paragraph, on the bottom of p191.

Comment: You are right; the explanation in the book is brief, and the point is a key-point in understanding the semantics of f-o logic. Two possibilities : try to find a better book (there are) or try to do the exercise and ask again if you need help.

Comment: @mdegges - The basic issue is : how to "verify" when $\forall x P(x)$ is true ? Two passages : first, you "throw away" the quantifier, reducing the problem to $P(x)$; but now you have a free variable. Then, how to "verify" when $P(x)$ is true, with $x$ free ? Substitute $x$ with a constant $c$ (that is, with a *name* of an object in the domain). Now, assuming for simplicity that $x$ is the only free variable in the formula, the result will be an *instance* $P(c)$ (that is $P[c/x]$), that is a meaningful sentence taht is *true* or *false* according to the interpretation $[P]$ of $P$. 1/2

Comment: @mdegges - But the original formula have a universal qunatifier $\forall$. What does it mean to be true in the domain? That $P$ holds for every object in the domain. So, for all objects $a$ of the domain, $P$ holds for $a$. This boils down to: "change" in turn the *denotation* of the name $c$, (these are the *c-variants*) and you will "run across" all objects of the domain. So, the *instance* $P[c/x]$ must be *true* for all *c-variants* that you can obtain letting $c$ "varying" along the domain. 2/2